# Using data.table within functions

Tags: r, data.table

I've got a `list` of `data.table`s and I'd like to modify the `list` elements before applying `rbindlist`. In particular, I'd like to remove columns that are not the same, add a column containing the name of the particular `list` element and set a fixed order of the columns so that the right columns get bound (a kind of mimicking the behaviour of `ldply` from the `plyr` package). I wrap all these steps into an `mapply` so that it looks like in this example:

```
library(data.table)
file_list <- list(cars1 = as.data.table(cars),
                  cars2 = as.data.table(cars),
                  cars3 = as.data.table(cars))
 # creating a column that is not contained in the other list elements
file_list$cars1[,speed2 := speed*100]

common_cols <- c("dist", "speed")

list_to_bind <- mapply(function(DT, DTname){
  cols_to_delete <- setdiff(colnames(DT), common_cols)
  if (length(cols_to_delete) > 0)
    DT[, cols_to_delete := NULL, with = FALSE]
  DT[, elemname := DTname]
  setcolorder(DT, c("elemname", common_cols))
  return(DT)
}, file_list, names(file_list), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Running this code leads to the following warning:

> In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(elemname, DTname)) :
>     Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a copy of the whole table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or been created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid key<-, names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. Also, in R<=v3.0.2, list(DT1,DT2) copied the entire DT1 and DT2 (R's list() used to copy named objects); please upgrade to R>v3.0.2 if that is biting. If this message doesn't help, please report to datatable-help so the root cause can be fixed.

The following modified `mapply` command doesn't lead to this warning:

```
list_to_bind <- mapply(function(DT, DTname){
  DT2 <- copy(DT)
  cols_to_delete <- setdiff(colnames(DT2), common_cols)
  if (length(cols_to_delete) > 0)
    DT2[, cols_to_delete := NULL, with = FALSE]
  DT2[, elemname := DTname]
  setcolorder(DT2, c("elemname", common_cols))
  return(DT2)
}, file_list, names(file_list), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

I assume, the warning is due to the fact that `R` passes a copy of the actual parameter to the function without the explicit `copy` command. However, why does this warning only occur at `DT[, elemname := DTname]` and not earlier? Isn't `R` also taking a copy of the list element to execute the `DT2 <- copy(DT)` command (i.e., to fetch `DT`)? Or if it only copies the element when it is changed, why doesn't it throw the warning at `DT[, cols_to_delete := NULL, with = FALSE]`?

Comment: If you're trying to workaround limitations of `rbindlist` in v1.9.2 there are quite a few improvements in v1.9.3 to `fill=` and `use.names=`. Search the [github homepage](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/) for "rbindlist". Does that help?

Comment: @MattDowle This definitely helps to tidy up my code, thanks a lot!